# Can I avoid an audit by submitting documents early?

Tags: canada, canada-revenue-agency, audit

I make a lot of charitable donations every year (I donate 10% of my net income to my church), lots of people in my church get audited every year. Is there a way I can avoid getting audited by just submitting my receipts from the church with my tax return? Or do I just have to deal with the audits every year?

Comment: That's not an audit.  It's an information request and is quite standard.  Just mail them the requested receipts.

Answer (score 5):

I personally don't think submitting early is going to make a difference. While the exact process of selecting who to audit will always remain secret, it's obvious that certain things will make your tax return more likely to get flagged for potential audit. Large charitable donations would be one of those things.

I strongly recommend you do not send your receipts to the CRA until they ask for them, as they do not expect people to include the receipts with their returns, and the department processing the mailed-in tax forms might lose them, or store them away somewhere that could create a future hassle if/when you get a letter asking you to send in copies of the receipts. Instead, just keep them filed away with your tax stuff for at least 5 years.

While the CRA is likely to want evidence of large donations, it's unlikely that they will bother to do a careful audit of the entire return - they will often just ask for specific pieces of evidence (like bus passes if you claim the public transit credit). So it's really not as much of a hassle to deal with as you might be thinking.

Comment: We've been audited more than once, and my in-laws get audited every year. Pretty much everyone I know in my church has been audited for their donations. Hence why I want to just give the CRA my receipts before they audit us again. I don't send the originals, you can submit online with the CRA, but only with a case number as far as I know.

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but I really don't think they would do anything with copies you send in before they ask for them. For the same reason you can't upload them online ahead of time: they have to open the auditing case first so that the receipts can get linked to it.